# Can't access local environment of my project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a Laravel project that i recently tried to set in my local environment. 
The project is REST-API based, and all of the requests are made with API.
When i try to send an API request to my local environment project i get UnauthorizedRequestException.

Since i am not fully familiar with Laravel i couldn't tell where do i set the authentication.

I tried to trace the error but all i get is a bunch of functions that do not help me. or at least that's what i think because non of them shows where i can find the authentication settings.

This is the error i get in the browser when i try to send an API request:

```
{
success: false,
errors: "Not Authorized",
data: null
}
```

This is an error that was set up in case of unauthorized access and the code for it is:

```
App::error(function(UnauthorizedRequestException $exception, $code)
{
    $headers = array(
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'       => '*',
        );

     return Response::json(
                array(
                    'sucess' => false,
                    'errors' => $exception->getMessage(),
                    'data'   => null,
                ),
                $exception->getCode(),
                $headers
     );
});
```

This code is located in app/start/global.php.

If someone knows where i can set the authentication so i can start working on my local environment let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Have you logged into your application on your local environment? You don't mention you actually being authenticated, just you getting an unauthorised exception. Which as far as I can tell from above, there is no bug..

Comment: i don't think i did. the thing is, this is not my project. i am now working on it but i didn't build it...do you know why do i get this authorized exception? maybe the localhost is not set as an allowed user?

Comment: Does the application have a authentication (login) endpoint? I think you may be getting out of your depth. Can you contact the owner of the project?

Comment: Unfortunately not...i think it might have something to do with the headers maybe? because it says in the routes that the route i am using is secured and i need an auth token in order to use it. the "auth token" is a header? because i do send "X-Auth-token" header in the regular app (not in the localhost)